# How to use a DepthBuffer as InputAttachment in Vulkan?

Tags: c++, graphics, vulkan

I have some trouble implementing my DepthBuffer as InputAttachment of a secondary subpass. I want to use the depth information of my first subpass. How can I archieve this? It seems that my current code gives me just an empty buffer..

My depth buffer is setup as follows:

```
create_info.imageType       = VK_IMAGE_TYPE_2D;
create_info.format          = VK_FORMAT_D32_SFLOAT;
create_info.mipLevels       = 1;
create_info.arrayLayers     = 1;
create_info.samples         = VK_SAMPLE_COUNT_1_BIT;
create_info.tiling          = VK_IMAGE_TILING_OPTIMAL;
create_info.usage           = VK_IMAGE_USAGE_DEPTH_STENCIL_ATTACHMENT_BIT | VK_IMAGE_USAGE_INPUT_ATTACHMENT_BIT;
```

I then use the following layout transition:

```
VkImageMemoryBarrier layout_transition_barrier{};
{
    barrier.sType                   = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_IMAGE_MEMORY_BARRIER;
    barrier.srcAccessMask           = 0;
    barrier.dstAccessMask           = VK_ACCESS_DEPTH_STENCIL_ATTACHMENT_READ_BIT
                                    | VK_ACCESS_DEPTH_STENCIL_ATTACHMENT_WRITE_BIT;
    barrier.oldLayout               = VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_UNDEFINED;
    barrier.newLayout               = VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_DEPTH_STENCIL_ATTACHMENT_OPTIMAL;
    barrier.srcQueueFamilyIndex     = VK_QUEUE_FAMILY_IGNORED;
    barrier.dstQueueFamilyIndex     = VK_QUEUE_FAMILY_IGNORED;
    barrier.image                   = image;
    barrier.subresourceRange        = { VK_IMAGE_ASPECT_DEPTH_BIT, 0, 1, 0, 1 };
}
```

This works totally fine for rendering..
The VkAttachmentReference I use has the layout `VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_DEPTH_STENCIL_READ_ONLY_OPTIMAL` and I use it as an `VK_DESCRIPTOR_TYPE_COMBINED_IMAGE_SAMPLER`.
In my fragment shader I then use `layout (set = 0, binding = 1) uniform sampler2D inputDepth;` to access it, however without any success.. the information I get is only zeros for any color channel.

---

Further I use this dependency:

```
VkSubpassDependency dependency{};
{
    dependency.srcStageMask     = VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_COLOR_ATTACHMENT_OUTPUT_BIT;
    dependency.dstStageMask     = VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_TOP_OF_PIPE_BIT;
    dependency.srcAccessMask    = VK_ACCESS_COLOR_ATTACHMENT_WRITE_BIT
                                | VK_ACCESS_DEPTH_STENCIL_ATTACHMENT_WRITE_BIT;
    dependency.dstAccessMask    = VK_ACCESS_INPUT_ATTACHMENT_READ_BIT;
    dependency.dependencyFlags  = VK_DEPENDENCY_BY_REGION_BIT;
}
```

and this descritpion

```
static VkAttachmentDescription depth_input_attachment{};
{
    depth_input_attachment.format           = VK_FORMAT_D32_SFLOAT;
    depth_input_attachment.samples          = VK_SAMPLE_COUNT_1_BIT;
    depth_input_attachment.loadOp           = VK_ATTACHMENT_LOAD_OP_LOAD;
    depth_input_attachment.storeOp          = VK_ATTACHMENT_STORE_OP_DONT_CARE;
    depth_input_attachment.stencilLoadOp    = VK_ATTACHMENT_LOAD_OP_LOAD;
    depth_input_attachment.stencilStoreOp   = VK_ATTACHMENT_STORE_OP_DONT_CARE;
    depth_input_attachment.initialLayout    = VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_DEPTH_STENCIL_ATTACHMENT_OPTIMAL;
    depth_input_attachment.finalLayout      = VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_DEPTH_STENCIL_ATTACHMENT_OPTIMAL;
}
```

Comment: Well... what is your current code?

Comment: just added excerts of my code :)

Comment: There seems to be some missing code here. For example, your layout barrier says that the image is in ATTACHMENT_OPTIMAL layout. But you say that the `VkAttachmentReference` specifies the READ_ONLY_OPTIMAL layout. So either there are layout transitions that you're not telling us about, or you're lying to Vulkan and the Vulkan validation layers you ought to be using should have caught those errors.

Comment: @NicolBolas the renderpass will do the transitions though it needs a subpass dependency from the first subpass (writing to the attachment) to the second (which reads from it).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're doing subpasses (and not multiple render passes) and want to use your depth buffer as an **inputAttachment** and want to use an attachment as an input for a second **sub**pass,

`layout (set = 0, binding = 1) uniform sampler2D inputDepth`

is not the correct syntax to sample from that in your shader.

Sampling from an input attachment requires a special syntax:

`layout (input_attachment_index = n, binding = m) uniform subpassInput inputDepth;`

This also requires a descriptor of type `VK_DESCRIPTOR_TYPE_INPUT_ATTACHMENT` instead of `VK_DESCRIPTOR_TYPE_COMBINED_IMAGE_SAMPLER`. Note that the actual descriptor for input attachments does not require a sampler.

If you're instead trying to sample your depth attachment in a second render pass, make sure that the storeOp of the attachment description is set to store.

Comment: Now the Validation Layer `[SC]` says: `Shader consumes input attachment index 0 but not provided in subpass`.
However my color input attachment I still can read.. It's just the depth attachment I have trouble with :(

Comment: If you want to sample from an input attachment, you need to specify it in your subpass description via the pInputAttachments member.

Comment: Well I actually did that.. :/
I am an Idiot - I just forgot to bind it with `vkUpdateDescriptorSets` :D
Thank you very much for your time and help :)